# How to add Download functionality

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i have add export functionality in my application. It's work very well. Now i want to add auto download functionality after completion of Export function.
using c# asp.net

Comment: Anything you have tried? Any piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by:  string file = "";

```
    file = "Path of File Name to Download";
    if (file != "")
    {
        context.Response.Clear(); 
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Path.GetFileName(file));
        context.Response.WriteFile(file);
        context.Response.End();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function populateIframe(id,path) 
{
    var ifrm = document.getElementById(id);
    ifrm.src = "download.php?path="+path;
}
</script>
```

Place this where you want the download button(here we use just a link):

```
<iframe id="frame1" style="display:none"></iframe>
<a href="javascript:populateIframe('frame1','<?php echo $path; ?>')">download</a>
```

The file 'download.php' (needs to be put on your server) simply contains:

```
<?php 
   header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['path']);
   readfile($_GET['path']);
?>
```